# Dev-c++ compilation and linking problems

Tags: c++, dll, dev-c++

I've inherited a dll file and its source code and I need to rebuild it. The dll file exports functions that are needed in another application. It was originally made using an older version of dev-c++ (probably a few years back). When I try to build it, the compilation process goes fine and the object files are created, but I get an error during the linking process. Here's an excerpt from the output of the compile log.

```
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '--no-export-all'
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '--add-stdcall-alias'
```

I am looking for a solution to this problem, solution meaning being able to rebuild the dll. I do not have contact with the creator of the source code. Any suggestions, ideas or answers would be much appreciated. I am using dev-c++ 5.11 and using the TDM-GCC 4.9.2 32-bit compiler.

Comment: i think you should use old version of g++. which version of g++ you use?

Comment: When I run g++ --version I get GCC 4.9.2
It's the same one as used by dev-c++.